# Como configurar Symfony em subDominio?

Tags: php, htaccess, symfony

Tenho uma aplicação escrita em Symfony 3 que eu desejo publicar em um subdominio. A aplicação atualmente é hospedada na locaweb.

O meu site principal é este: example.com

O objetivo é criar um subdominio especifico para esta aplicação, de modo que fique como: **symfony**.example.com.

Pelo painel da hospedagem eu posso criar fácilmente subdominios, porem eles são obrigatoriamente dentro da pasta public_html.
Desta forma, mesmo que eu crie um subdominio, a pasta ainda fica acessível através do site principal.

Por exemplo:

O site principal tem o nome example.com que aponta para a pasta public_html/

O subdominio tem o nome synfony.example.com que aponta para a pasta public_html/outro_projeto.

Como eu posso garantir que, mesmo estando em uma subpasta, o conteúdo da aplicação não seja acessível?
Eu imaginei criar alguma regra de htaccess para isto, mas não estou certo em como fazer ela ser executado no site principal e ser ignorada no subsite.